# Identify set for Star Wars parts, dark grey base with 4 studs and embossed Star Wars logo

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Would greatly appreciate help in matching this to a Star Wars set.  Front and back 2"x 2"plate with top back ridge.  Dark gray color.  I have nine pieces.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is [Tile, Modified 6 x 6 x 2/3 with 4 Studs and Embossed 'STAR WARS' (30566)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30566#T=C):

[image: 30566]

It appeared in [4 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=30566&in=S) back in 2000, always in dark gray. The sets are:

- 3340-1 Star Wars #1 - Sith Minifig Pack
- 3341-1 Star Wars #2 - Luke/Han/Boba Minifig Pack
- 3342-1 Star Wars #3 - Troopers/Chewie Minifig Pack
- 3343-1 Star Wars #4 - Battle Droid Minifig Pack

Comment: Thank you!  I'm a bit disappointed that this isn't part of a large set.

Comment: They're easier to buy in smaller sets and you can add it to anything as large as you like.